# Magento product's category

Tags: mysql, magento

I have to list products with its category or categories, I have only products' SKU by it I need to find which category it belongs, so I want to know in which magento table this information stay.

ie:  for sku 52429, it is categorized into 3 categories.   the report would show all 3 category trees:

Bl > Hair Care > Styling products

Bl > Natural & Organic > Hair Care > Styling Products

Bl > Our Brands > Pureology > Stylers

Thanks!
Richa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento categories are stored in `catalog_category_entity` (pk is `entity_id`). To find the relationship between a product and a category, use `catalog_category_product`. Its structure is simple:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+
| category_id | product_id | position |
+-------------+------------+----------+
|           3 |          5 |        1 |
|           3 |          6 |        1 |
|           3 |          7 |        1 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
```

So, to get all categories for a product:

```
select cc.* from catalog_category_entity cc
   join catalog_category_product cp on cc.entity_id = cp.category_id
   where cp.product_id = {{your product id}};
```

---

EDIT to note that the info you are looking for (to display category trees) is in the category table itself. An excerpt of the columns (some omitted):

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
| entity_id | parent_id | path  | position | level | children_count |
+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
|         1 |         0 | 1     |        0 |     0 |             65 |
|         2 |         1 | 1/2   |        1 |     1 |             64 |
|         3 |         2 | 1/2/3 |        1 |     2 |              9 |
|         4 |         2 | 1/2/4 |        2 |     2 |             18 |
|         5 |         2 | 1/2/5 |        3 |     2 |              9 |
+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+-------+----------------+
```

You can use split on that `path` column to get the category IDs of all the categories in the path, and load their names for the report.

Comment: Thanks! but By applying this method, if any product have category like bl > skin > face, it shows two entries 1) bl> skin and 2)bl > skin > face, do you have any idea how to handle this or fix this issue.

Comment: That data result is correct if the product is in both categories. Can you please describe what you would expect to see in this case?

Comment: It should display only bl > skin > face b'cz face is final subcategory(of skin), which product belongs. (why it showing category also?)

Answer (score 7):

First load up the product model

Either by ID

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

or by attribute (SKU)

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', '52429');
```

Now you can load the category IDs

```
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

Then to get the full category objects

```
foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) { 
  $categories[] = Mage::getModel(’catalog/category’) 
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
    ->load($categoryId);
}
```

Now to get the parent of each category

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
  $category->getParentCategory();
}
```

This is all you need i think.

Comment: +1 for the effort and good approach, But I have to know all related table to fetch any category because I have to directly access the magento database by mysql.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. But I wish you good luck! Post the solution if you succeed, it would probably be interesting to others. There is of course another way of doing it by accessing the magento resource models that would probably work faster and/or better. But i haven't got the time right now to figure it out.